# Pandas: parse .csv string type number with dot as thousand separator to int instead of float

Tags: python, pandas, csv

It's a .csv with items and prices. The latter already come rounded (without decimal) but if the price is more than 999, then I have to deal with the thousand separator.

```
item, price
foo, 12
bar,678
baz, 1.200


`df.dtype` returns:
item         object
price       float64
```

If I try to convert to `int` it truncates the number. So instead of 1.200 (one thousand two hundred) I get 1 (one)

Ps: I winded up deleting the dots with regex, but there has to be a proper way to handle this situation.

Comment: [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) has a `thousands` parameter.

Comment: this is the answer! I had to learn how to pass the parameter inside `map`. This is the result: `df = pd.concat(map(lambda a : pd.read_csv(a, thousands="."), joined_list), ignore_index=True)`. Lots of fun with Python today! Thanks @BigBen . What should I do with this post? Since the answer is in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @BigBen there's a `pd.read_csv` parameter called `thousands` used to indicate the thousand separator. There's also a `decimal` parameter which may be useful too.